# SwiftUI 5 TextField `.number` format does not work with decimal

Tags: swiftui

I have a `TextField` that has `.number` as the format, but it will not allow me to enter a decimal in the number.

```
TextField("Hours", value: $hours, format: .number)
```

This seems trivial, but I am not sure what to put here to ask the right question. There is nothing in the log that is outside of my expected output. Any thoughts?

If I type `20` in the text field and then try to put a `.` betwene the `2` and the `0` it deletes the `0`.

All `TextField`s with the `.number` format on all of my views

Video Showing Behavior
https://streamable.com/egywcq

Comment: What is the type of `hours`?

Comment: `public var hours: Optional<Float> = nil`

Comment: When you say "it will not allow me to enter a decimal in the number" do you mean that you can't type a '.'?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem.  Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: hard to reproduce, i don't understand why it would let me

Comment: Try removing the optional

Comment: Seems to be an iOS 17 issue.  I found the same problem in my code.  Works fine in iOS 16.x, but not in 17.x.  Can't type the ".". It seems iOS 17 changed the .number format.  In iOS 16, "7." was valid, but in iOS 17, it's not and gets reformatted to "7".  It seems to take about a second for the .number formatter to decide you're done typing and reformats the value without the decimal point.  However if some other state change causes the view to refresh, this reformatting will happen immediately and make it seem like you can't enter the ".".  Would need to see more of your code to help further.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with something like this:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    return formatter
}()
```

and add formatter in TextField:

```
TextField("Hours", value: $hours, formatter: formatter)
```

Comment: tried this too, same result